# How do I only get future dates only instead of future and past dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So this is the issue that I'm facing. Currently I'm running into an issue with a piece of my code. What I'm looking for is to only grab things that haven't reached a specific end date and if it's already ended do not grab, but currently it's grabbing everything.

I've tried doing some IF statements for example:

```
{=IF('Sheet1'!$G:$G>TODAY(),IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!$D:$D,SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$E:$E=$B$1,ROW('Sheet1'!$E:$E)-MIN(ROW('Sheet1'!$E:$E))+1),ROWS('Sheet1'!$D$2:D2))),""),"")}
```

NOTE: This is an Array

But running this still gives me Category's that have already past the End Date.

For Column Reference:

Sheet1 Column D = Category

Sheet1 Column E = Name

Sheet1 Column G = End Date

B1 = Name of person (Currently a drop down list of multiple names)

The Current code I have without the IF statement is as follows: (Again Array)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!$D:$D,SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!$E:$E=$B$1,ROW('Sheet1'!$E:$E)-MIN(ROW('Sheet1'!$E:$E))+1),ROWS('Sheet1'!$D$2:D2))),"")
```

What I want it to result in is if the End Date is in the past to essentially skip over and move onto the next criteria instead of grabbing it based of `TODAY()` function. With the result of only capturing future Category's with future End Dates.

Any help would be much appreciated!

-Maykid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!$D:$D,SMALL(IF(('Sheet1'!$E:$E='Sheet1'!$B$1)*('Sheet1'!$G:$G>TODAY())>0,ROW('Sheet1'!$D:$D)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement similar to

```
if(edate(range)>Today(),return this data,0)
```

Insert your data for `return this data`.